# Is ASUS X550LB-XX021D compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: asus, compatibility

I'm thinking about switching to Ubuntu,i've had enough of Windows's BSOD,trojans etc.I want a secure and clean operating system for my laptop.I'm not a hardcore gamer,i barely play games on my system...i only use it for movies,surfing on the internet and school projects.So,my question is,is Ubuntu compatible with my laptop?(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Why would it not? Since not a lot of us will have this system and Ubuntu is free we have a Live DVD to test hardware. Please download Ubuntu, burn it to a DVD and start it. It will be slow but if all is working during that session 99% chance everything will work when installed. If needed do make a backup of your files you do want to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using ASUS K55VM with Ubuntu since 12.04 version and never had an issue. You can choose Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS or 14.10 based on your choice. For people who feel stability is top priority, LTS (Long Term Support) versions are recommended.

Your laptop is not on the [list](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Asus/) (per say, so isn't mine). I think your X550LB should work fine with Ubuntu. Installation procedure can be [viewed here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).

If you doubt it, then use [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and run Ubuntu from USB for trial and test everything like wifi, sound, battery backup hours, heating, bluetooth, file transfer, trackpad check etc. This will make you feel more confidant.

After installation, follow [these instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html) to turn it into a productive system.

Answer (score 0):

I've owned three asus netbooks and five asus desktop motherboards.  Asus appears committed to Linux and with it Ubuntu as well.  I don't feel I'd be going out on a limb to say you have nothing to worry about.  All that I would suggest is to make sure to have your computer connected to the internet with an ethernet connection during the installation so that it can download and drivers it needs during the installation.